# robots.txt - just a guess about wild-card

Tags: robots.txt

so if I disallow tempPage, does it mean tempPage_1, temp_Page_2, tempPage_x are also disallowed? I tried to google this up, but I don't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If tempPage_1, temp_Page_2, tempPage_x are subdirectories of tempPage then, **yes**, they are blocked.

2) If they are parallel directories then, **no**, they are not blocked.

3) If they are separate files then, **no**, they are not blocked.

Assuming #1 is not true, to block them all you would use:

```
disallow tempPage*
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is incorrect...

Comment: what is incorrect?

Comment: Google, Yahoo, and Microsoft honor wildcards in the disallow statement

Answer (score 0):

Yes those pages would be blocked, assuming they are at the same directory level. There is no `*` wildcard in robots.txt, except a single `*` for the User agent.

In other words this...

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /tempPage
```

...would block `yoursite.com/tempPage`, `yoursite.com/tempPage_1`, `yoursite.com/temp_Page_2`, `yoursite.com/tempPage_x`.